# Why does RSTP send proposal bit and agreement bit as '1' initially?

Tags: cisco, switch, spanning-tree, ieee-802.1w

From a recent Wireshark capture of a RSTP BPDU on a switch, both proposal and agreement bits were set to '1'.
In my understanding, initially both switches 'propose' themselves as root. The better root is elected, and the other switch replies with the agreement bit set.

Also, after the whole syncing process, the root's proposal bit is '0' but agreement bit is still '1'. Why is this so?

[image: Proposal and agreement are '1']

[image: Proposal is still '1' after sync]

Comment: does this answer the question? https://community.cisco.com/t5/switching/rstp-working-how-to-use-bpdu-agreement-flag/td-p/1606059. According to this ref: the answer is "the flag is ignored, so it doesn't matter if it is set or not"

Comment: @Effie, yeah this feels right, although I feel it is an incorrect design to do so.

Comment: i think this is written in the link too

Comment: Please, never use an image for text. Simply copy the text, paste it into the question, and use the Preformatted-text option (`{}`). You can obfuscate any text prior to posting the question.